# SQL Union displaying wrong result

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table2
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table3
```

Result is

```
247811

58599

76
```

But actually

table1 has **247811** rows

table2 has **76** rows

table3 has **58599** rows

Comment: That result appears to be (approximately) correct - `UNION` does *not* make any guarantees about result ordering (absent an explicit `ORDER BY` clause)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Are you sure there is difference in `table` rows count?

Comment: @OP: `SELECT 'table1' as tname, COUNT(id) FROM table1 UNION ...` should resolve your problem

Comment: so, you are saying its a mistake of SQL Developers that they failed to make SQL up to your expectations. You should email all the sources about it.

Comment: @jarlh  I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @ARr0w already mailed, but for now would find a workaround rather than commenting unnecessarily

Comment: @Shaharyar yes there is a difference in table rows count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `union` operator makes no gaurantees about the order. If you want to order the results in a particular way, you'd have to do so explicitly, with an `order by` clause. Note also that `union` removes duplicates, so you'd better use `union all`. E.g.:

```
SELECT   cnt
FROM     (SELECT 't1', COUNT(id) FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 't2', COUNT(id) FROM table2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 't3', COUNT(id) FROM table3) t
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

if your problem depends on `order by` please `order by` your select after `union`, if you have a problem with count?(in your example there is a different count 79 and 76) it depends on that you use `count(id)` it is not same is `count(*)`, `count(id)` ignores every `null` in `Id` column, `count(*)` it is count of your table rows

Comment: there is no null in any row column id of any of the three tables